# How to put hat on a subscript without pushing it downward?

Tags: subscripts

I try to put hat on the subscript in `>_{A_j}`, i.e., `>_{\widehat{A}_j}`, but this pushes down `A` with the subsubscript `j` further downward fouling line spacing. How do I put hat on subscript while maintaining its vertical position?

Comment: How about `x_{\smash{\widehat{A}_j}\vphantom{A_j}}`?

Comment: @Werner it is good it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `\smash{<stuff>}` to get rid of the height and depth of `<stuff>` and then augment it with a `\vphantom` of whatever height/depth you want it to look like:

```
x_{\smash{\widehat{A}_j}\vphantom{A_j}}
```